# Reversing a linked list using recursion

Tags: c++, recursion

I don't know where I'm going wrong. Output shows 1 upon inputting 1 2 3 -1 (-1 to terminate insertion of nodes). Help is appreciated!
I can't seem to find the error in my code that is resulting in wrong output upon different test cases.
Other approaches to the same problem are also welcome.
Any tips so that i won't commit such errors in the future, along with some fundamentals(generally tips) of linked lists

```
#include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    class Node
    {
    public:
        int data;
        Node *next;
    
        Node(int data)
        {
            this->data = data;
            next = NULL;
        }
    };
    Node *insert()
    {
        int data;
        cin >> data;
        Node *head = NULL;
        Node *tail = NULL;
        while (data != -1)
        {
            Node *n = new Node(data);
            if (head == NULL)
            {
                head = n;
                tail = n;
            }
            else
            {
                tail->next = n;
                tail = tail->next;
            }
            cin >> data;
        }
        return head;
    }
    
    void print(Node *head)
    {
        Node *temp = head;
        while (temp != NULL)
        {
            cout << temp->data << " ";
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
    
    Node *rev_LL(Node *head)
    {
        if (head == NULL || head->next == NULL)
        {
            return head;
        }
    
        Node *smallAns = rev_LL(head->next);
        Node *temp = smallAns;
        while (temp->next != NULL)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->next = head;
        head->next = NULL;
        return smallAns;
    }
    
    int main()
    {
        Node *head = insert();
        print(head);
        cout << endl;
        cout << "After reversing the Linked list : " << endl;
        rev_LL(head);
        print(head);
        cout << endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to assign the return value of `rev_LL` to `head` instead of just ignoring that.

```
int main()
{
    Node *head = insert();
    print(head);
    cout << endl;
    cout << "After reversing the Linked list : " << endl;
    //rev_LL(head);
    head = rev_LL(head); // assign the result
    print(head);
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, scratched my head for far too long over something as silly as this.

Comment: @Dcypher fwiw, i didnt find a warning flag for this case, but there is the attribute [`[[nodiscard]]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/nodiscard) that encourages the compiler to issue a warning when a returned value is not used.